# is it true that $A$ is a closed subset of $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $A$ be a subset of a metric space $(X,d)$. Suppose there exists $r > 0$ such that whenever $x,y \in A$ and $x \ne y$, then $d(x,y) > r$. Then is it true that $A$ is a closed subset of $X$?

I tried to show that the complement of A  is open by showing that every point is an interior point but was not able to do it.

Comment: Does $X$ contain a point $p$ which is a limit point of $A$ but which is not in $A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $z\in\overline{A}$. Since we are in a metric space, There exists a sequence $x_n\in A$ such that $d(x_n,z)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. If the sequence $(x_n)$ would contain infinitely many distinct elements, we would be able to find $n<m$ such that $x_n\neq x_m$ and $d(x_n,x_m)<r$, contradicting the assumption. Therefore there exists some $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have $x_n=x_N$. It follows that the limit $z$ of the sequence is $x_N$, which belongs to the set $A$. Thus $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a point $p$ in the complement of $A$, and consider the open ball of radius $r/2$ centered at $p$. Why can at most a single point of $A$ possibly be inside that ball? Why does that mean you can find a (possibly smaller) ball around $p$ which doesn't intersect $A$ at all?